# How to use the randomly generated code for secure access?

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication

I have been thinking of securing the login system by using a nice long random char password produced on the server and send it as an hidden field to the client. Then I will append the credentials with that password and encrypt it. But then I realized that since, how I append will be visible in code in javascript, its decryption will be fairly easy. So, is there any way that this technique of appending can be safe or SSL is the only option?

Comment: What is the exact target? What is the exact security issue you wish to close? Is it man-in-middle or simple authentication? SSL is the answer for security on the wire.

Comment: The website has a login system, I want that the user credentials when they land in bad guys hand are encrypted. So I tried encrypting then by appending them to a key generated on the server, it will be random but now I learnt that how I append will be visible in javascript AND THUS CAN BE DECRYPTED. I don't want to go with SSL, finding an alternative and thought of this method.

Comment: That's only the case with symmetric encryption, you could use asymmetric encryption. But as the encryption is still done in Javascript [it is a BAD IDEA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116883/are-there-any-asymmetric-encryption-options-for-javascript). Use SSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that is sent via HTTP is visible and could be intercepted. Use HTTPS at least for login pages.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the way AntiForgeryToken is implemented in MVC. Here is good link that could help you figure out what you need to do and to give you some ideas.

- http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/archive/2010/05/22/anti-forgery-request-recipes-for-asp-net-mvc-and-ajax.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to minimize the impact of "bad guys" in the middle, SSL is the best way. And when there is proven ways (SSL), why need to reinvent the wheel?